# Navigating through folders with php

Tags: php

I am trying to make a code to navigate through a directory in PHP

```
function navigate($path){
    $directorio = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/' . $path;
    $scan = scandir($directorio);
    return $scan;
}
   session_start();
   $dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/';

if(ISSET($_POST['datei'])){
    echo $_POST['datei'];
    $_SESSION['actualdir'] = $dir . $_POST['datei'];    
    $scanner = navigate($_SESSION['actualdir']);
}
if(!ISSET($_POST['datei'])){
    $scanner = scandir($dir);
}
```

The $scan and $scanner variables are arrays that go to a dropdown to choose the next folder. However my code only works twice.

Example:

We start in folder.

Then the dropdown shows nextfolder

We are now in folder/nextfolder.

We choose anyfolder again.

The program goes to folder/anyfolder instead of folder/nextfolder/anyfolder.

Any ideas? I guess I should keep saving the current directory somehow. Yet I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: What is your desired goal here? You can use a loop to navigate to your destination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use recursive function to do that.

```
    function navigate($path){
          static $scanned = array();
          $dir = scandir($path,1);

          foreach ($dir as $obj) {
              if(strlen($obj) > 2){
                  if(is_dir($path.$obj)){
                      //directory
                      $scanned = indir($path.$obj.'/');
                  } else {
                      //file

                  }
              }


          }
          return $scanned;
      }
```

Comment: this function will give you recursive folders 
like folder/subfolders and it's subfolders